# Resizing Borderless wxFrame in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, window-resize, resizable, borderless

Hi i have a borderless wxFrame but it is not resizable. I want to make the frame resizable just like when it is resizable with a border. I am using wxRESIZE_BORDER and wxBORDER_NONE style properties. I know i have to catch the mouse event manually and then implement it but am not able do that. I have also looked at the shaped sample directory but there also there is no "border-less resizable frame". I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and wxWidgets 3.1.5.   Is this doable/possible in wxWidgets and is there any example of the same?

Comment: why do you want to use border less window? Also, you said that `I know i have to catch the mouse event manually and then implement it but am not able do that. ` Why? Can you show some code and explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: The design/looks of the app(as given by the ui designer) is such that there is no border that is we have a custom frame.

Comment: It's because i do not know in which order should i do things. Like how many steps should be there. If i know the steps then i can start trying to implement it myself first. For example, in step 1 should i check where is the current cursor position. Then in the second step if the cursor is just 5 or 10 pixels away(inwards or outwards) of the frame then i should change the cursor looks. In the third step if the user holds mouse left down then change the frame size accordingly. Can you tell me the exact steps that i have to follow? Then i can try to implement it.

Comment: for that you probably better off catching wxEVT_ENTER_WINDOW. But it is very strange. Can you confirm that it is actually a borderless window and not just basic border that just simply not visible? You will have to do a lot of stuff manually which is already done for you on the OS/toolkit level. It vfeels like all you will do is re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: But the steps are pretty much the same - get the cursor coordinates, change the cursor accordingly then on timer check if there was a mouse click and then move. If it is - calculate the new size and call event.Skip(). However, all this is unreliable as mouse enter/leave events can be fired on entering the window children.

Comment: On top of that it may not work consistently on all platforms and did I mentio you will be re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: If it is possible to switch to QT, take a look at this: https://www.qt.io/blog/custom-window-decorations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the basic machinery needed to allow a frame to be resized without using a resize border.   It basically shows Igor's comments above.

```
#include "wx/wx.h"

#include <wx/timer.h>
#include <wx/dcbuffer.h>
#include <wx/version.h>

#if __WXGTK__
#define BORDERLESS_FRAME_STYLE (wxCAPTION | wxCLOSE_BOX)
#else
#define BORDERLESS_FRAME_STYLE (wxCAPTION | wxCLOSE_BOX | wxBORDER_NONE)
#endif // __WXGTK__

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();

private:
    enum ResizeMode
    {
        ResizeNone,
        ResizeFromTop,
        ResizeFromUpperLeft,
        ResizeFromLeft,
        ResizeFromLowerLeft,
        ResizeFromBottom,
        ResizeFromLowerRight,
        ResizeFromRight,
        ResizeFromUpperRight
    };

    // General event handlers
    void OnBgPanelPaint(wxPaintEvent&);

    // Event handlers for resizing
    void OnLeftDownForResizeFromLowerRight(wxMouseEvent&);
    void OnLeftDownForResizeFromLowerLeft(wxMouseEvent&);

    void OnLeftUp(wxMouseEvent&);
    void OnMouseCaptureLost(wxMouseCaptureLostEvent&);
    void OnResizeTimer(wxTimerEvent&);

    // Resizing helper functions
    void DoDragBasedResize();
    void StartResize(wxWindow*, const wxPoint&);
    void CompleteResize(bool doFinalResize = false);

    // Data and objects needed for resizing.
    wxTimer m_resizeTimer;
    int m_resizeFrequency;
    int m_resizeAreaLength;
    ResizeMode m_resizeMode;
    wxPoint m_resizeStartPoint;
    wxSize m_initialFrameSize;
    wxPoint m_initialFramePosition;

    wxWindow* m_clickToResizeFromLowerRightWindow;
    wxWindow* m_clickToResizeFromLowerLeftWindow;
    wxWindow* m_curResizeWindow;

    // GUI controls
    wxPanel* m_bgPanel;
};

MyFrame::MyFrame():wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Resizing Demo", wxDefaultPosition,
                           wxSize(400, 300), BORDERLESS_FRAME_STYLE)
{
    // Set up the UI.
    m_bgPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
                            wxTAB_TRAVERSAL|wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE);
    m_bgPanel->SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_PAINT );
    m_bgPanel->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &MyFrame::OnBgPanelPaint, this);

    wxSizer* mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    mainSizer->Add(m_bgPanel, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
    SetSizer(mainSizer);
    Layout();

    // Initialize the data needed for resizing.
    m_resizeMode = ResizeNone;
    #if wxCHECK_VERSION(3,1,0)
        m_resizeAreaLength = FromDIP(20);
    #else
        m_resizeAreaLength = 20;
    #endif // wxCHECK_VERSION

    m_resizeTimer.Bind(wxEVT_TIMER, &MyFrame::OnResizeTimer, this);
    m_resizeFrequency = 50;
    m_curResizeWindow = NULL;

    // Set window and event handlers for resizing from lower right.
    m_clickToResizeFromLowerRightWindow = m_bgPanel;
    m_clickToResizeFromLowerRightWindow->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN,
        &MyFrame::OnLeftDownForResizeFromLowerRight, this);
    m_clickToResizeFromLowerRightWindow->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,
        &MyFrame::OnLeftUp, this);
    m_clickToResizeFromLowerRightWindow->Bind(wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST,
        &MyFrame::OnMouseCaptureLost, this);

    // Set window and event handlers for resizing from lower left.
    m_clickToResizeFromLowerLeftWindow = m_bgPanel;
    m_clickToResizeFromLowerLeftWindow->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN,
        &MyFrame::OnLeftDownForResizeFromLowerLeft, this);
    m_clickToResizeFromLowerLeftWindow->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,
        &MyFrame::OnLeftUp, this);
    m_clickToResizeFromLowerLeftWindow->Bind(wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST,
        &MyFrame::OnMouseCaptureLost, this);
}

void MyFrame::OnLeftDownForResizeFromLowerLeft(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    wxPoint p = event.GetPosition();
    wxSize sz = m_clickToResizeFromLowerLeftWindow->GetClientSize();

    // Check if the click is in the lower left of the window.
    if ( p.x < m_resizeAreaLength &&
        sz.GetHeight() - p.y < m_resizeAreaLength )
    {
        StartResize(m_clickToResizeFromLowerLeftWindow, p);

        m_resizeMode = ResizeFromLowerLeft;
        SetTitle("Resize From lower left in progress...");
        SetCursor(wxCursor(wxCURSOR_SIZENESW));
    }
    else
    {
        event.Skip();
    }
}

void MyFrame::OnLeftDownForResizeFromLowerRight(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    wxPoint p = event.GetPosition();
    wxSize sz = m_clickToResizeFromLowerRightWindow->GetClientSize();

    // Check if the click is in the lower right of the window.
    if ( sz.GetWidth() - p.x < m_resizeAreaLength &&
        sz.GetHeight() - p.y < m_resizeAreaLength )
    {
        StartResize(m_clickToResizeFromLowerRightWindow, p);

        m_resizeMode = ResizeFromLowerRight;
        SetTitle("Resize from lower right in progress...");
        SetCursor(wxCursor(wxCURSOR_SIZENWSE));
    }
    else
    {
        event.Skip();
    }
}

void MyFrame::OnLeftUp(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    if ( m_resizeMode != ResizeNone )
    {
        CompleteResize(true);
    }
    else
    {
        event.Skip();
    }
}

void MyFrame::OnMouseCaptureLost(wxMouseCaptureLostEvent&)
{
    if ( m_resizeMode != ResizeNone )
    {
        CompleteResize(false);
    }
}

void MyFrame::OnResizeTimer(wxTimerEvent&)
{
    DoDragBasedResize();
}

void MyFrame::DoDragBasedResize()
{
    wxMouseState ms = ::wxGetMouseState();
    wxPoint curMousePsn = ms.GetPosition();
    wxPoint dragVector = curMousePsn - m_resizeStartPoint;

    wxSize newSize(m_initialFrameSize);
    wxPoint newPsn(m_initialFramePosition);

    if ( m_resizeMode == ResizeFromLowerRight )
    {
        newSize = wxSize(m_initialFrameSize.GetWidth() + dragVector.x,
                         m_initialFrameSize.GetHeight() + dragVector.y);
    }
    else if ( m_resizeMode == ResizeFromLowerLeft )
    {
        newSize = wxSize(m_initialFrameSize.GetWidth() - dragVector.x,
                        m_initialFrameSize.GetHeight() + dragVector.y);

        newPsn = wxPoint(m_initialFramePosition.x + dragVector.x,
                         m_initialFramePosition.y);
    }

    SetSize(newPsn.x, newPsn.y, newSize.GetWidth(), newSize.GetHeight());
}

void MyFrame::StartResize(wxWindow* win, const wxPoint& p)
{
    m_curResizeWindow = win;
    m_resizeTimer.Start(m_resizeFrequency);
    m_resizeStartPoint = m_curResizeWindow->ClientToScreen(p);
    m_curResizeWindow->CaptureMouse();
    m_initialFramePosition = GetPosition();
    m_initialFrameSize = GetSize();
}

void MyFrame::CompleteResize(bool doFinalResize)
{
    if ( doFinalResize )
    {
        DoDragBasedResize();
    }

    m_resizeTimer.Stop();
    m_resizeMode = ResizeNone;

    SetTitle("Resize complete");
    SetCursor(wxCursor(wxCURSOR_ARROW));

    if ( m_curResizeWindow && m_curResizeWindow->HasCapture() )
    {
        m_curResizeWindow->ReleaseMouse();
    }

    m_curResizeWindow = NULL;
}

void MyFrame::OnBgPanelPaint(wxPaintEvent&)
{
    wxAutoBufferedPaintDC dc(m_bgPanel);

    dc.Clear();
    wxPen pen(*wxRED,5);
    dc.SetPen(pen);

    // Draw some red marks to indicate the lower right resize area
    wxPoint lowerRight = m_bgPanel->GetClientRect().GetBottomRight();
    dc.DrawLine(lowerRight - wxPoint(0,m_resizeAreaLength), lowerRight);
    dc.DrawLine(lowerRight, lowerRight - wxPoint(m_resizeAreaLength,0));

    // Draw some red marks to indicate the lower left resize area
    wxPoint lowerLeft = m_bgPanel->GetClientRect().GetBottomLeft();
    dc.DrawLine(lowerLeft - wxPoint(0,m_resizeAreaLength), lowerLeft);
    dc.DrawLine(lowerLeft, lowerLeft + wxPoint(m_resizeAreaLength,0));
}

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    public:
        virtual bool OnInit()
        {
            MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame();
            frame->Show();
            return true;
        }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

This only shows resizing if the click is in the lower right corner of a panel covering the client area of the frame.  I tried to add enough generality that if you have another control covering the lower right, you should be able to set that control to be `m_clickToResizeWindow` in the code above.

There is one case where that might not work however. I could be wrong, but I think some native controls completely consume mouse clicks and won't even generate a wxMouseEvent.  In this case, resizing won't be possible if such a control is in the lower right.

There are some parameters that can be changed to modify the resizing behavior.  The `m_resizeAreaLength` determines how close to the edge a click can be to start the resizing process.  I've set this to 20 DIPs.  The `m_resizeFrequency` determines how frequently the size is updated during a resize operation.  I've set this to 50ms.  A smaller value will provide smoother updates.  In this example, I drew some red marks on the lower right to indicate the resizing area. This is completely unnecessary and can be removed.

This example only shows resizing based on a click on the lower right.  However it shouldn't be too hard to modify the code to allow only horizontal resizing based on a click on the right edge or vertical resizing based on a click on the bottom edge.  However, it might get complicated if there are multiple controls covering the left or bottom edges.  This system only works well if there is one control covering those edges.

---

**edit**: I've updated the code to show resizing from both the lower left and lower right while keeping the rest of the frame in the appropriate position.

This can be further expanded to allow for resizing from other edges or corners.  To do so it will be necessary to:

1. add a pointer for the window that will be used to receive the click starting the resize.
2. add a left down handler for that window to start the process.
3. Bind the new left down handler, the existing left up handler, and the existing capture lost handler for the window.
4. add to the `DoDragBasedResize` method setting a new size and position for the frame appropriate for the type of resizing being done.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I think one example is wxComboBox where you will get a different behavior based on the OS/toolkit. And there is a very old ticket about it. So if such control will be at the border of the frame - you will be out of luck. Or you will have to be really precise with the coordinates.

Comment: @NewPagodi When adding the same functionality for the bottom left corner, i notice that when i use SetWidth() and SetHeight() methods then the size of the frame is increased or decreased starting from the rightmost part. Is there a way to instead increase the Width and height from the other(left) side of the frame? Like by changing the origin or something. For now i am using this resizing for rightmost part only. Thanks for the example.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to resize based on dragging from both the lower left and lower right corners.  I know this was complicated, but it ended up being even more complicated than I expected it to be.